# How to fix an error that is occurred when install the pod in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, pod-install, deepar

I'm using the rwa_deep_ar package for the DeepAR feature in the Flutter project.
When I install the pod in MacOS, I see the following error.

[image]

I want to know how to fix this error and how to use the DeepAR for iOS in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Kill the app
2. Run: flutter clean
3. Run: flutter pub get
4. Run: cd ios && pod install --repo-update

Answer (score 0):

1. Podfile change `platform :ios, '13.0'` target set
2. Delete the folder and file from the project iOS folder

   - .symlinks folder
   - Pods folder
   - Podfile.lock file
3. flutter clean
4. flutter pub get
5. cd ios
6. pod install --repo-update

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to download and install cocoapods on MacOS.

sudo gem install cocoapods
sudo nano export PATH=$PATH:/YOUR PATH
pod init
open Podfile
pod install